# How to disable empty <p> tags in comment_text()

Tags: comments

Im not sure if you guys have encountered this problem, but WordPress appends empty `<p>` tags before and after the body of text from the `comment_text()` function.

Strangely, when you `echo get_comment_text()` or `echo $comment->comment_content` (same thing) the empty `<p>` tags disappear before and after the body of text.

This is entirely exclusive to a call to `comment_text()`. If you'd like to recreate it the problem, give your `<p>` tags top and bottom padding.

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` you'll see all of the functions each comment is run through before it's output. I'd guess it's the last one, wpautop, which adds p tags in place of line breaks:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wptexturize'            );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_chars'          );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable',      9 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'force_balance_tags', 25 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_smilies',    20 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop',            30 );
```

You can `remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop', 30 );` to confirm, but you'll lose paragraphs entirely.

Comment: Yea i can confirm that its the last one. Though the paragraphs are still intact. Thanks Milo. This is the second time you help me out. Really appreciate it. Do you think WordPress is aware of this problem?

Comment: i take that back, you're right, paragraphs are lost when removing the filter. I reverted to giving the `<p>` tags 0 padding.

Comment: @VicePrez it's not a problem it's a feature :)